# Android keyboard flickers on and off when typing

Tags: keyboard, screen

When I type on my Android keyboard, it flickers on and off, I'm not sure why. I'm using Samsung Galaxy S3 if it matters.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Disable the hardware overlays from the developer options.

1. Go to **Settings - Developer options**
2. Tick **Disable HW overlays**.

It should drastically fix the flickers or at least help until the fix is merged.